# Characterisation of exponential and logarithm.

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

If we have $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow{}\mathbb{R}$ and if $f(x)=\exp(x)$ then we have

$$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y) $$

Similarly we have for the logarithm the property,

$$g(xy)=g(x)+g(y) $$

But is this also a necessary condition? In the sense that if we have a function that satisfies such a property then it should be the exponential, logarithm respectively (excluding the trivial case $h(x)\equiv 0$)?

Comment: You need some sort of continuity assumption.  See the closely related [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)

Comment: $f(x)=2^x$ also satisfies the equation.

Comment: @KentaS Yes, but that can also be written as $f(x) = 2^x = e^{2\log(x)} = e^y$. So we can view that as a specific case of $\exp({x})$.

Comment: I'm saying the claim, as stated, is incorrect. You need conditions such as $f(1)=e$ to pin down the function further. Alternatively, you can try to say the equation characterizes functions of the form $f(x)=e^{ax}$ for some constant $a$. However, even this is incorrect, as @lulu points out.

Comment: @KentaS Ok let's include the assumption of continuity, and extend the $e^x$ to $e^{ax}$ does the claim then hold, and is there a known proof for it?